# Tor with Python: Actively Refusing Connection

Tags: python, tor

I'm trying to interface with Tor using Python, but it keeps refusing my connection. Here is my code:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl
conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")
```

I've also tried:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl
conn = TorCtl.connect()
```

Both yield the following error:

```
Failed to establish socket: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Any ideas why this is happening/how I might fix it?

Comment: Assuming this is a *nix system, run `netstat -tnlp` in the shell to verify the service is actually running on port 9051.

Comment: Unfortunately I am running on Windows. But regardless, even if the service is not running on port 9051, the second piece of code should take care of that (I think)

Comment: It should be a similar syntax for Windows. Try typing the same command, and try various other `netstat` arguments if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, first I've seen that particular error. My first guess would be a local firewall, try running 'telnet localhost 9051' to troubleshoot.

On a side note [TorCtl has been deprecated](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/torctl-deprecation-and-stem-plans) in favour of [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/).